# Postgresql 9.5 Performance Issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-9.5

I have a PostgreSQL 9.5 instance running on Windows 8 machine with 4GB of RAM.This server is mainly used for inserting/updating large amounts of data via copy/insert/update commands, and seldom for running select queries.

Here are the relevant configuration parameters I changed:

```
max_connections = 100  
shared_buffers = 512MB  
effective_cache_size = 3GB  
work_mem = 12233kB  
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB  
min_wal_size = 1GB  
max_wal_size = 2GB  
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7  
wal_buffers = 16MB  
default_statistics_target = 100
```

After setting in `postgresql.conf`. I run the select query to fetch large amount of record of 29000 in postgresql but it takes 10.3 seconds but the same query takes 2 seconds for execution in MSSQL.

So my query is how to improve the perfermance in postgresql.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` of your SQL statement ( [formatted text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), no screenshots or upload it to http://explain.depesz.com). You are likely comparing the performance of your SQL client to _display_ 30k rows, not the performance of the server

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an index on your table and use this web site for a better setting parametres [pgtune](http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua) this site provide you with the ideal parametres for your postgres.